# Integrating Ideal with stripe into Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, payment, stripe.js

Ive made the app based on this tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/express

How do I now change the payment method from creditcard to ideal?
ideal docs: https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal#create-source

Question: where do I call the `stripe.createSource({` source?

---

Things I've tried: 
Changing the `stripe.customers.create({` in the app.js to the `stripe.createSource({`

changing data fields in the .pug file

making edits in the `stripe.charges.create({`

---

If you have any suggestions let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the documentation, which has code samples:
https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal

The basic steps are:

1. Create a source object
2. Redirect your customer to the redirect[url] on your new source
3. Create a webhook endpoint that listens to when sources become chargeable, and create a charge

You can see a demo app that uses Stripe Sources, including iDEAL here:
https://github.com/thorsten-stripe/sources-demo

Comment: Where do I create a source object? in the app.js file?